# run ec2 user-data on startup for every new launch

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-config

Is there a way to automatically run user-data for every ec2-instance launched for all AMIs? I want to configure where it will run a script without user putting it in. Is it possible with AWS config?

Comment: It would be possible but you would have to automate this in whatever environment you are using for deployment

Comment: thats what I am trying to do. Maybe use lambda to run the user data script after instance is launched as the trigger.

Comment: You need to give us more information in your question.. how are you launching those EC2 instances?

Comment: launching through console. Basically every time an instance is launched by anyone, I want a script to run in the user data field for every instance.

Comment: You can't do that, but you could use SSM automation (triggered by EventBridge) to run a command/script whenever an instance is launched

Comment: That makes sense. How can i create that automation? just add the script in the editor when I create the automation?

Comment: First of all you would have to make sure the AMIs have the SSM agent running on them, then you would configure EventBridge to be triggered on ec2 instance launch event, and as a target you would have an SSM run command document which run whatever command/script you need

Comment: but how can SSM agent already be running, if a new instance was just launched?

Comment: SSM agent must be installed as a service on the AMI

Comment: User-data is not part of the AMI data.  But if you supplement AMI with a Launch Template you can provide User data.  It can work with any compatible AMI! 
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-launch-templates.html